# Sql: Select in STR_TO_DATE Range

Tags: mysql, sql

My sql is working for one date, now i want to select by range, what can i do to add the range date?

```
SELECT 
        products.id, 
        products.name, 
        (select ifnull(sum(stocks.qty),0) from stocks where stocks.pid=products.id and DATE(stocks.created_at) = STR_TO_DATE('15,4,2020','%d,%m,%Y') ) as stock_in_today,

        (select ifnull(sum(loadings.qty),0) from loadings where loadings.pid=products.id and DATE(loadings.created_at) = STR_TO_DATE('15,4,2020','%d,%m,%Y') ) as total_loadings_today,

        (select ifnull(sum(stocks.qty),0) from stocks where stocks.pid=products.id) as total_stock_till_date,

        (select ifnull(sum(loadings.qty),0) from loadings where loadings.pid=products.id) as total_loadings_till_date,

        ((select ifnull(sum(stocks.qty),0) from stocks where stocks.pid=products.id and DATE(stocks.created_at) < STR_TO_DATE('15,4,2020','%d,%m,%Y'))-(select ifnull(sum(loadings.qty),0) from loadings where loadings.pid=products.id and DATE(loadings.created_at) < STR_TO_DATE('15,4,2020','%d,%m,%Y'))) as opening_balance,

        ((select ifnull(sum(stocks.qty),0) from stocks where stocks.pid=products.id and DATE(stocks.created_at) <= STR_TO_DATE('15,4,2020','%d,%m,%Y'))-(select ifnull(sum(loadings.qty),0) from loadings where loadings.pid=products.id and DATE(loadings.created_at) <= STR_TO_DATE('15,4,2020','%d,%m,%Y'))) as closing_balance

        from products
```

my view

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated subqueries.  Here is an example:

```
select d.dte,
       p.id, p.name,
        (select coalesce(sum(s.qty), 0)
         from stocks s
         where s.pid = p.id and
               s.created_at >= d.dte and
               s.created_at < d.dte + interval 1 day
        ) as stock_in_today,
        . . .
from products p cross join
     (select date('2020-01-01') as dte union all
      select date('2020-02-01')
     ) d
```

And so on for the rest of the subqueries.

Note the changes I've made to the query:

- Added table aliases, so table references are easier to write and read.
- Use standard date format for the dates literals.
- Changed the date logic to use direct comparisons instead of functions.

This query can make use of an index on `stock(pid, created_at)`.

Comment: @EmmaMfinanga . . . The results would only be multiplied if you had duplicates in the `d` derived table.

Comment: I dont have duplicated id